# how I can exit from a loop in one second using Runtime?

Tags: java, runtime, timeunit

how I can exit from a loop in one second using Runtime?
I want use this code

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    Runtime runtime = Runtime.getRuntime();
    long usedMemory = runtime.totalMemory()-runtime.freeMemory();
    int mbytes = (int) usedMemory/1000; // Used memory (Mbytes)
    String str="a";

        while (somthing < one second ) {


       }
}
```

Comment: please explain more what you want to do.

Comment: I want to count how many string can I add in one second like 
while (somthing < one second) {
 str=str + "a"; 
} 
@user2310289
System.out.println(str);

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();

while((System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime)<=1000){
     str=str + "a"; 
}
```

Comment: I want to count how many string can I add in one second like
while (somthing  < one second) {  
   str=str + "a";
         }
System.out.println(str);

Comment: ` long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
        String str ="a";
        while((System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime)<=1000L){
             str=str + "a"; 
        }
        System.out.println(str.length());`

Comment: I can print str.length() but not str !!

Answer (score 1):

ok to do this you need to records the start time, and then compare it to the current time as you go.

```
    long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
    String str="a";
    while (true) {
        long now = System.currentTimeMillis();
        if (now - start > 1000)
             break;

        // do your stuff
        str=str + "a"; 
    }

    System.out.println (str);
```

The above code will probably spend more time getting the time that doing the stuff you want though

Comment: That because I did not put your code in my code.  I simply put a comment saying //do your stuff.  I will update.

Comment: On my slow machine, I can do it about 37443 times.  `System.out.println (str1.length());`

Comment: I can print str.length() but not str !!

Comment: Please update your code in your question.  Then we can see what is wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
 long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
 while((System.currentTimeMillis()-startTime)<1000){
// Your task goes here
}
```

Comment: I want to count how many string can I add in one second like while (somthing < one second) { str=str + "a"; } System.out.println(str);

Answer (score 0):

Write your code in while loop. It will exit the loop after 1 second.

```
long start = System.currentTimeMillis();
long end = start + 1000; //  1000 ms/sec
while (System.currentTimeMillis() < end)
{
    // Write your code here
}
```

Answer (score 0):

i think that you can use something like this if you don't really need to use Runtime.

```
public class test {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
    long startTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    long usedMemory = runtime.totalMemory()-runtime.freeMemory();
    int mbytes = (int) usedMemory/1000; // Used memory (Mbytes)
    String str="a";

    while (currentTime-startTime<1000) {
        currentTime = System.currentTimeMillis();
    }
}
```